# how to solve this : $R(m)=12+5m -0.4m^2$?

Tags: quadratics

How to solve this : $R(m)=12+5m-0.4m^2$?

Jeremy's junkers keeps track of the revenue it makes from selling used exhaust manifolds. they have found that the revenue is a function of the number sold and this can be modeled by the quadratic function, where $R$ is the revenue in hundreds of dollars, and $m$ is the number of manifolds. How many manifolds should they sell to earn a revenue of $\$2400$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggest you to explain a little bit how you tried to solve it, so other people could help you better. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

The question asks us for the number, $m$, of manifolds sold when $R=24$ (since $R$ is measured in hundreds of dollars), thus we wish to solve this equation:

$$24=12+5m-.4m^2$$
$$\implies -\frac{2}{5}m^2+5m -12 =0$$
Using the quadratic forumula we obtain:

$$m =\frac{-5 \pm \sqrt{25-4(-2/5)(-12)}}{2(-2/5)}$$
$$= \frac{-5 \pm \frac{\sqrt{145}}{5}}{2(-2/5)}$$
$$=\frac{25 \pm \sqrt{145}}{4}$$

Thus we see that there are two quantities of manifolds, $ m \approx 3.24$ and $m \approx 9.26$ which will yield our desired revenue.